# Angular factory provider is ignored

Tags: angular, ngrx

maybe someone can help.
I have this factory provider setup:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: SettingsEffects,
    useFactory: () => {
      const actions = inject(Actions);
      const userSettingsService = inject(UserSettingsService);
      const storeService = inject(SettingsStoreService);

      return new SettingsEffects(actions, userSettingsService, storeService, remoteRoutes, FEATURE_NAME);
    },
    deps: [Actions, UserSettingsService, SettingsStoreService],
    multi: true,
  },
],
```

and in my module, I import it like this:

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([SettingsEffects]),
```

but when I run my application, I get this error:

[image]

So, I can gather from that, it's not using my factory at all.
Does anyone know why?

Here is the full module:

```
import { NgModule, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

import { UiComponentsModule } from '@trunarrative-ui/ui-components';
import {
  SettingsEffects,
  SettingsStoreService,
  UserSettingsService,
  featuresFactory,
  settingsEffectsFactory,
} from '@trunarrative-ui/core';
import { FEATURE_NAME } from '@trunarrative-ui/journeys';

import { RemoteEntryComponent } from './entry.component';
import { remoteRoutes } from './entry.routes';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [RemoteEntryComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: SettingsEffects,
      useFactory: () => {
        const actions = inject(Actions);
        const userSettingsService = inject(UserSettingsService);
        const storeService = inject(SettingsStoreService);

        return new SettingsEffects(actions, userSettingsService, storeService, remoteRoutes, FEATURE_NAME);
      },
      deps: [Actions, UserSettingsService, SettingsStoreService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UiComponentsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(remoteRoutes),
    StoreModule.forFeature(FEATURE_NAME, featuresFactory(FEATURE_NAME, remoteRoutes)),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([SettingsEffects]),
  ],
})
export class RemoteEntryModule {}
```